# Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Let $a \in \{1,2,...,n-1,n\}$....

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the commutative ring
>   $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Let $a \in \{1,2,...,n-1,n\}$. Suppose $a$ is coprime
>   to $n$ then prove $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a unit. Note $\bar{a}$
>   denotes the congruence class of $a~(mod ~n)$.

I need to prove this but running into some difficulties so far I have:

Since $a$ is coprime to $n$ by Bezout's lemma we have $\exists ~x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=ax+ny$. After this I don't know how to proceed I get I want to show that there is a $b$ in the ring such that $ab=\bar{1}$ but I'm not sure how to show it's existence.

Comment: Reduce $\pmod n$.

Comment: Please explain what do I reduce?

Comment: What do you get by reducing "$1=ax+ny$" ?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do that could you explain please. $1=ax$ so $ax=\bar{1}$ so $a \in R$ is a unit?

Comment: ? Does my argument work now?

Comment: $$1\equiv \overline{1}\pmod n\\ax+ny\equiv?\pmod n$$

Comment: $ax+ny \equiv \bar{1} \mod n \implies ax \equiv \bar{1} \mod n$?

Answer (score 1):

$\exists ~x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=ax+ny$ so let $b=x+ny$ then $\bar{a}.\bar{b}=\bar{a(x+ny)}=\bar{ax}+\bar{any}=\bar{ax}+\bar{ny}=\bar{1}$.$(any\equiv ny\pmod n)$